# Why does git push fails with "Operation timed out"?

Tags: git, git-push

```
MacMini $ git push origin master
Counting objects: 1916, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1751/1751), done.
Read from remote host codebasehq.com: Operation timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: pack-objects died with strange error
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@codebasehq.com:xx/xx/xx.git'
```

Comment: Isn't this issue a bit like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781013/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-pack-objects-died-with-strange-error ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Contemporary UTM ([Unified Threat Model](https://www.fortinet.com/resources/cyberglossary/unified-threat-management)) firewalls can mess with outgoing data if they falsely identify traces of malware, packed data, or insecure commands in the stream... and these false alarms happen pretty frequently. Such security devices on your network or the destination side could explain why some projects push up okay and others are dropping the connection.

If that's the case, you may avoid the trigger if you use a different protocol for this connection, e.g. `ssh://` or `https://` instead of `git://`.

Comment: how do i change the protocol?

Comment: @Alexander - Use ‘git remote’ commands to change the URL to use the ‘https://...’ URL instead: https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you have a bad network connection. Can you access codebasehq.com, especially with the network protocol you use. Have you a correct proxy server configuration? Can you pull other projects?

Comment: Yes. I can push other projects upto codebasehq.com... it's just a few that are causing problems...

Comment: Semms like a timeout or some weired data patterns. Is this always at the same position or at the same time? You might try to look at the data stream with wireshark or tcpdump to see if there is any suspicious.

Comment: Yes. It always happens at one specific point... is there verbose git command that would identify the rejected file?