# Can't push new git repository to github

Tags: git, github

I've been working on a local git repository and everything has been working well. Today it was time to share the code, and I created a github repository, but I can't push to it. I tried all the compression and pruning methods I could find. This has happened before and my only solution was to create a new repo and move everything over and git init again. Since this has happened for a second time, I would really like to run this down.

```
 Tim$ git remote add origin git@github.com:tbbooher/cba_fitwit.git
 Tim$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 7964, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2915/2915), done.
Read from remote host github.com: Connection reset by peer
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: pack-objects died with strange error
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:tbbooher/cba_fitwit.git'
```

On the same machine (MacBook Pro), I'm able to push and pull with four other repos, but I still suspect some ssh trickery. Compressing happens very quickly, then everything slows *way* down at this point, and creeps along to about 11% and then fails as above.

```
Writing objects:  10% (865/7964), 2.37 MiB | 203 KiB/s
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does git push fails with "Operation timed out"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140715/why-does-git-push-fails-with-operation-timed-out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with my router. I went to a new location and everything pushes just fine, now I am curious how to correct my router.

It is interesting to note, that once I did the initial push, the router can handle it just fine.

Comment: But you say that pushing to different repos works? Even behind the same router? Second question: What about ssh-ing to a machine somewhere? Does ssh on port 22 work at all?

Comment: Some routers perform packet inspection to detect malware or dangerous sequences. This is probably your case: that's why this only happens on a single repo (which apparently has some misleading character sequence) and not on all of your repos. So, if your router has any "security" related option, try disabling it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `https://` address instead of the `git` one.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't push using https or git protocol. You have to use ssh.

Comment: this fails too:remote add origin https://tbbooher@github.com/tbbooher/cba_fitwit.git
Tim$ git push -u origin master

Comment: i also created an entirely new repo with the same result

Comment: @svick: nope, recently https also supports pushes (and it has also some speed advantages over ssh): see http://cl.ly/2H0V3x3s3s2z3R2w3O2L/Screen_Shot_2011-10-18_at_9.14.55_AM.png

Comment: @bonhoffer: is the problem still present if you connect to the internet via a different network (e.g. home ISP)?

Comment: i'll have to go to a local wifi and explore . . . and the https:// was removed from my comment above, but it is there :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It pointed me in the right direction.