# GIT fails when pushing large files/sites

Tags: git, github

Im getting this error when I try to push an extremely large site with lots of files. The error I get is this:

```
Compressing object: 100% (28532/28532), done.
Read from remote host xxxxx.beanstalkapp.com: Connection reset by peer
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to 'xxxxx'
```

Does anyone know how to push large object or a large amount of objects without losing connection?

Comment: similar error in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792937/cant-push-new-git-repository-to-github

Answer (score 2):

Off-hand I would ask about this on ServerFault, as it smells like a networking problem not a Git problem (says the recovering sysadmin).