# Git stuck on writing Objects 33% then "Killed by signal 2"

Tags: git, github

```
git push origin master
Counting objects: 41, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
Writing objects:  33% (11/33), 1.30 MiB | 14.00 KiB/s
```

There is gets stuck and I have to do:

```
^C
Killed by signal 2.
```

I can push other repos to github, but not this one.
My filesize is:

```
173.9 MB on disk) for 10584 items
```

My git version:

```
git --version
git version 2.2.1
```

I just recently installed 2.2.1 from 1.9.3
I'm running Yosemite 10.10.1

The internet so far has been unhelpful on this error. I don't want to try cloning to a new repo because I don't want to lose the commits from the last week I've worked on this project.

EDIT: Solved by restarting router >:[

Comment: I solved this by restarting my router - typical!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to lose the commits from the last week I've worked on this project.

Commit early, commit often :)

I found this issue when looking for your problem [Can't push new git repository to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792937/cant-push-new-git-repository-to-github)

How long have you been getting this error?  Have you tried using a different internet connection?  Have you tried amending https:// to the git address?

Comment: If I start a new repo I will have to delete my last repo, thus losing my streak on github is what I mean. My Heroku remote is https:// and it will not push to that either. I'm not really prepared to go hunt down someone elses internet to see if it's my router causing the problem...

Comment: In that thread that I linked, the person's router was carrying out erroneous packet inspection causing the issue.

Comment: The thing is it was pushing fine from here all week. What changed? I have only been adding images to my repo today.

Comment: Hey @HannahLouisaCarney I'm glad the solution worked, could you please mark my response as correct, thank you.

Comment: @HannahLouisaCarney Probably with the new commits (the images) the total amout to be pushed got too big for something.